# How to pass query parameter of BigQuery insert job in Cloud Workflow using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform, workflow

I encountered an error when running Cloud Workflow that's supposed to execute a parameterised query.
The Cloud Workflow error is as follow:

> "message": "Query parameter 'run_dt' not found at [1:544]",
> "reason": "invalidQuery"

The Terraform code that contains the workflow is like this:

```
resource "google_workflows_workflow" "workflow_name" {
  name            = "workflow"
  region          = "location"
  description     = "description"
  source_contents = <<-EOF

main:
  params: [input]
  steps:
    - init:
        assign:
          - project_id: ${var.project}
          - location: ${var.region}
          - run_dt: $${map.get(input, "run_dt")}
          
    - runQuery: 
        steps:
          - insert_query:
              call: googleapis.bigquery.v2.jobs.insert
              args:
                projectId: ${var.project}
                body:
                  configuration:
                    query:
                      query: ${replace(templatefile("../../bq-queries/query.sql", { "run_dt" = "input.run_dt" } ), "\n", " ")}
                      destinationTable:
                        projectId: ${var.project}
                        datasetId: "dataset-name"
                        tableId: "table-name"
                      create_disposition: "CREATE_IF_NEEDED"  
                      write_disposition: "WRITE_APPEND"  
                      allowLargeResults: true
                      useLegacySql: false
                      partitioning_field: "dt"
    - the_end:
            return: "SUCCESS"
EOF
}
```

The query in the query.sql file looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table-name`
WHERE sv.dt=@run_dt
```

With the code above the Terraform deployment succeeded, but the workflow failed.

If i wrote "input.run_dt" without double quote, i'd encounter Terraform error:

> A managed resource "input" "run_dt" has not been declared in the root module.

If i wrote it as $${input.run_dt}, i'd encounter Terraform error:

> This character is not used within the language.

If i wrote it as ${input.run_dt}, i'd encounter Terraform error:

> Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression token.

How can I pass the query parameter of this BigQuery job in Cloud Workflow using Terraform?

Comment: Where are `input` and `run_dt` coming from? A variable? Do you need to have the curly brackets?

Comment: It's the Cloud Workflow input parameter. The value is passed when executing the workflow in the console.

Comment: So that means you expect to be in the format like this when rendered properly: `${map.get(input, "run_dt")}`?

Comment: I'm using map.get function to pass an optional argument. I'm trying to follow the doc here: https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/passing-runtime-arguments

Comment: Without that line in the assign part, I still have the same error from Cloud Workflow: "Query parameter 'run_dt' not found at [1:544]

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution!
add queryParameters field in the subworkflow:

```
queryParameters: 
 parameterType: {"type": "DATE"}
 parameterValue: {"value": '$${run_dt}'}
 name: "run_dt"
```